# Do sqlcmd and SSMS not validate the server certificate if the server enforces the encryption?

Tags: sql-server, encryption, ssms, sqlcmd, sql-server-2019

I am hosting a few linux SQL Server 2019 instances. All connections to these instances should be encrypted, and therefore I enforce the encryption on the server side like this (following the official instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-encrypted-connections?view=sql-server-ver15#server-initiated-encryption)):

```sh
/opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set network.tlscert /etc/opt/mssql/mssql.pem
/opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set network.tlskey /etc/opt/mssql/mssql.key
/opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set network.tlsprotocols 1.2
/opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set network.forceencryption 1
```

The `mssql` certificate is a self-signed certificate.

To verify that connections are indeed encrypted I use the following script on the server:

```sql
select session_id, encrypt_option from sys.dm_exec_connections
```

When I execute this on the server I can see that indeed all connections are encrypted (except some entries without a session ID, which I assume are internal connections).

Now comes the puzzling thing: since the certificate is self-signed I expect clients to reject connections if they do not explicitly trust that certificate. However, that appears to only work if the client also explicitly enforces the encryption.

With `sqlcmd` on a Windows machine that does not trust the certificate I get the following:

```sh
> sqlcmd -S db.mydomain.com -U user -P password -Q "select encrypt_option from sys.dm_exec_connections where session_id = @@spid"
encrypt_option
----------------------------------------
TRUE

(1 rows affected)
```

It seems the encryption is working and I do not get a certificate validation error. However, if I enforce encryption on the client (i.e. `-N`) I get this:

```sh
> sqlcmd -S db.mydomain.com -U user -P password -Q "select encrypt_option from sys.dm_exec_connections where session_id = @@spid" -N
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.
.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Client unable to establish connection.
```

If I trust the certificate explicitly (i.e. `-C`) then the connection succeeds again:

```sh
> sqlcmd -S db.mydomain.com -U user -P password -Q "select encrypt_option from sys.dm_exec_connections where session_id = @@spid" -C -N
encrypt_option
----------------------------------------
TRUE

(1 rows affected)
```

If I add the self-signed certificate to my trusted root authorities on the client machine all connections (with or without `-N`) also succeed as expected.

The same happens when connecting through SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). When I just connect to the database with default settings, it works without validation error. If I select `Encrypt connection` in the `Connection Properties` then I get a certificate validation error.

Is this normal? I would have expected the client to always validate the certificate, regardless of who enforces encryption.